# Exception encountered while running quantum-enhanced support vector machines

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am trying to run the code of the notebook example [aqua/artificial_intelligence/qsvm_kernel_classification.ipynb](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/artificial_intelligence/qsvm_kernel_classification.ipynb). I save it in a python file and I have an exception at runtime the display of `{'A': 0, 'B': 1}`.

```
xception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7f78a3b23d30>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __del__
    self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
Abandon (core dumped)
```

The classical example worked fine: I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You said you saved the file as a python file? Did you extract the code from the code cells in the notebook and paste them into a python file? When I run the code in Jupyter Notebook it works fine for me. When I run it as a python file in the way I described earlier, it also runs fine for me. Can you provide a more detailed description to how you are running the file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's it, I copy/paste the code from the Notebook in a file on my Manjaro linux. As I told, I did the same for the classical version of the algorithm and it works. Maybe I am missing a package, the error trace is not helpful!!

Comment: I performed step by step debugging, and the exception occurs on the execution of the QSVMKernel: qsvm.run(quantum_instance)

Comment: So I made some progress: the error trace is usefull in fact: elf.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name) => that means the problem occurs because I close the 2 frames for Ad-hoc data which appears just before the display of {'A': 0, 'B': 1}. I close them because it seems to prevent the program to continue! If I set PLOT_DATA=False the programs runs well! So the question is 'Is it wrong to close the frame thtat way ?'

Comment: After looking at the error and your description more, I think it is an issue when the graphs are trying to be displayed. I would try to run the code in Jupyter Notebook just to see if it works there. Then we know the problem is isolated to trying to run the local python file. I would make sure you also have the matplotlib package installed, as I think it uses this package to display the graphs. You can install it through `pip install matplotlib`